# itertools' islice(count()) vs range()

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

Real quick one:

I just saw a [tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/17566/python-itertools#automating-sequences-with-islice-and-count) where they show we can use itertools' islice() and count() together like so:

```
for num in islice(count(), start, stop, step):
    print(num)
```

Is there any advantage in doing this instead of using range() ?

Comment: The tutorial isn't suggesting that this is a desirable alternative to `range`. It's just a contrived example used to demonstrate the usage of these functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any advantage in doing this instead of using range() ?

In this example there is no advantage and `range` would be the canonical solution.

`itertools.islice` becomes important if you have an arbitrary iterator (Especially which does not have random access behaviour like range).
Let's say you opened a file and want to ignore the first four lines and then print every second line.
With islice this becomes simply:

```py
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    for line in islice(f, start=5, stop=None, step=2):
        print(line)
```

One possible combination of `islice` with `counter`, which cannot be replaced with `range`, is if you have a non finishing loop (`stop = None`). Let's say you want to print all prime numbers starting from three.

```py
uneven_numbers = islice(count(), start=3, stop=None, step=2):
for num in uneven_numbers:
    if is_prime(num):
        print(num)
```

Here it es especially important that `uneven_numbers` is a generator and not a list (which would definitely use up your memory.)